# svg object didn't work along with the path Why not?

Tags: svg, svg-animate

Why didn't work along with path line?

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="595px" height="841px" viewBox="0 0 595px 841px" enable-background="new 0 0 595 841" xml:space="preserve"
   style="border:1px solid green">
   <g id="car">
      <path fill="#00CC92" d="M405.1,607.225c0,0,1.731-1.022,9.084-1.086c0.466-0.007,9.269-8.254,9.678-8.561
  c0.99-0.767,1.194-1.284,3.667-1.476c3.028,0,20.601-0.025,20.601-0.025s6.229-0.332,7.736,2.434
  c0.479,0.575,4.434,7.237,4.503,7.596c0,0,0.135,0.159,0.333,0.498c0.472,0.805,1.341,3.723,1.813,6.777
  c0.052,0.191,0.09,0.383,0.09,0.588v3.354c0,1.232-1.003,2.236-2.236,2.236h-0.102c0.064-0.365,0.102-0.734,0.102-1.119
  c0-3.705-3.002-6.707-6.707-6.707s-6.707,3.002-6.707,6.707c0,0.385,0.038,0.754,0.103,1.119h-29.271
  c0.064-0.365,0.103-0.734,0.103-1.119c0-3.705-3.003-6.707-6.708-6.707s-6.707,3.002-6.707,6.707c0,0.385,0.038,0.754,0.103,1.119
  h-2.338c-1.233,0-2.236-1.004-2.236-2.236v-3.354C400.002,613.97,399.728,610.13,405.1,607.225z M442.483,605.027l11.307-0.556
  l-1.246-2.798c0,0-0.767-2.235-3.354-2.235s-6.707,0-6.707,0V605.027z M421.076,606.298l3.296-0.217
  c0.716-1.591,1.546-2.459,2.306-2.612c0.92-0.192,1.311,0.798,1.311,0.798v1.571l12.258-0.805v-5.558
  c0,0-10.725-0.038-11.843-0.038s-2.689,1.954-2.689,1.954L421.076,606.298z M458.133,618.441c0,2.473-1.999,4.473-4.472,4.473
  s-4.472-2-4.472-4.473c0-2.471,1.999-4.471,4.472-4.471S458.133,615.97,458.133,618.441z M415.653,618.441
  c0,2.473-1.999,4.473-4.472,4.473c-2.472,0-4.472-2-4.472-4.473c0-2.471,2-4.471,4.472-4.471
  C413.654,613.97,415.653,615.97,415.653,618.441z">
    </path>
</g>
  <path fill="none" id="motionPath" stroke="green" stroke-width="8"
d="M400,618c0,0-127,66-112-52s134-264-90-251s-63-117-56-170"></path>
  <animateMotion xlink:href="#car" dur="5s" begin="click" fill="freeze" >
        <mpath xlink:href="#motionPath"></mpath>
  </animateMotion>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is due to the fact that the position of the car on the page is added to the (animated) position along the path.  So when you click the car, it jumps to effectively:

```
(motionPath.x + car.x, motionPath.y + car.y)
```

To fix this, you have to do one of two things:

1. position the motion path so it starts at (0,0) on the page (the top left), or
2. position the car at (0,0).

Since you want the car to start where it is on the page, so you can click on it, you are basically forced to choose option #1.

In the example below I've changed the motion path to one that starts at (0,0). I've just used a simple line because I don't have the time to work out the new coordinates for your whole path.

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="595px" height="841px" viewBox="0 0 595px 841px" enable-background="new 0 0 595 841" xml:space="preserve"
   style="border:1px solid green">
   <g>
      <path id="car"
            fill="#00CC92" d="M405.1,607.225c0,0,1.731-1.022,9.084-1.086c0.466-0.007,9.269-8.254,9.678-8.561
  c0.99-0.767,1.194-1.284,3.667-1.476c3.028,0,20.601-0.025,20.601-0.025s6.229-0.332,7.736,2.434
  c0.479,0.575,4.434,7.237,4.503,7.596c0,0,0.135,0.159,0.333,0.498c0.472,0.805,1.341,3.723,1.813,6.777
  c0.052,0.191,0.09,0.383,0.09,0.588v3.354c0,1.232-1.003,2.236-2.236,2.236h-0.102c0.064-0.365,0.102-0.734,0.102-1.119
  c0-3.705-3.002-6.707-6.707-6.707s-6.707,3.002-6.707,6.707c0,0.385,0.038,0.754,0.103,1.119h-29.271
  c0.064-0.365,0.103-0.734,0.103-1.119c0-3.705-3.003-6.707-6.708-6.707s-6.707,3.002-6.707,6.707c0,0.385,0.038,0.754,0.103,1.119
  h-2.338c-1.233,0-2.236-1.004-2.236-2.236v-3.354C400.002,613.97,399.728,610.13,405.1,607.225z M442.483,605.027l11.307-0.556
  l-1.246-2.798c0,0-0.767-2.235-3.354-2.235s-6.707,0-6.707,0V605.027z M421.076,606.298l3.296-0.217
  c0.716-1.591,1.546-2.459,2.306-2.612c0.92-0.192,1.311,0.798,1.311,0.798v1.571l12.258-0.805v-5.558
  c0,0-10.725-0.038-11.843-0.038s-2.689,1.954-2.689,1.954L421.076,606.298z M458.133,618.441c0,2.473-1.999,4.473-4.472,4.473
  s-4.472-2-4.472-4.473c0-2.471,1.999-4.471,4.472-4.471S458.133,615.97,458.133,618.441z M415.653,618.441
  c0,2.473-1.999,4.473-4.472,4.473c-2.472,0-4.472-2-4.472-4.473c0-2.471,2-4.471,4.472-4.471
  C413.654,613.97,415.653,615.97,415.653,618.441z">
    </path>
</g>
  <path fill="none" id="motionPath" stroke="green" stroke-width="8"
        d="M 0,0 L -250,-470" transform="translate(431,609)"></path>
  <animateMotion xlink:href="#car" dur="5s" begin="click" fill="freeze" >
        <mpath xlink:href="#motionPath"></mpath>
  </animateMotion>
</svg>
```

You may be wondering why, if the motion path has been moved, why it still being displayed in the same place?  The reason is that is that I've added a transform to the motion path so the start corresponds to the centre of the car, which is at approximately (431,609).  This doesn't affect the `animateMotion` because it only cares about what's in the `d` attribute. It ignores the `transform` attribute.

**Update**

Another alternative is to just position both the path **and** the car so that they start at (0,0). Then wrap the whole thing in a group that you transform to the final position.  That allows you to also use the `rotate` attribute in your animation.

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  width="595px" height="841px" viewBox="0 0 595 841"
   style="border:1px solid green">
   <g transform="translate(431,609)">
      <g id="car">
         <path transform="translate(-431,-626)"
            fill="#00CC92" d="M405.1,607.225c0,0,1.731-1.022,9.084-1.086c0.466-0.007,9.269-8.254,9.678-8.561
  c0.99-0.767,1.194-1.284,3.667-1.476c3.028,0,20.601-0.025,20.601-0.025s6.229-0.332,7.736,2.434
  c0.479,0.575,4.434,7.237,4.503,7.596c0,0,0.135,0.159,0.333,0.498c0.472,0.805,1.341,3.723,1.813,6.777
  c0.052,0.191,0.09,0.383,0.09,0.588v3.354c0,1.232-1.003,2.236-2.236,2.236h-0.102c0.064-0.365,0.102-0.734,0.102-1.119
  c0-3.705-3.002-6.707-6.707-6.707s-6.707,3.002-6.707,6.707c0,0.385,0.038,0.754,0.103,1.119h-29.271
  c0.064-0.365,0.103-0.734,0.103-1.119c0-3.705-3.003-6.707-6.708-6.707s-6.707,3.002-6.707,6.707c0,0.385,0.038,0.754,0.103,1.119
  h-2.338c-1.233,0-2.236-1.004-2.236-2.236v-3.354C400.002,613.97,399.728,610.13,405.1,607.225z M442.483,605.027l11.307-0.556
  l-1.246-2.798c0,0-0.767-2.235-3.354-2.235s-6.707,0-6.707,0V605.027z M421.076,606.298l3.296-0.217
  c0.716-1.591,1.546-2.459,2.306-2.612c0.92-0.192,1.311,0.798,1.311,0.798v1.571l12.258-0.805v-5.558
  c0,0-10.725-0.038-11.843-0.038s-2.689,1.954-2.689,1.954L421.076,606.298z M458.133,618.441c0,2.473-1.999,4.473-4.472,4.473
  s-4.472-2-4.472-4.473c0-2.471,1.999-4.471,4.472-4.471S458.133,615.97,458.133,618.441z M415.653,618.441
  c0,2.473-1.999,4.473-4.472,4.473c-2.472,0-4.472-2-4.472-4.473c0-2.471,2-4.471,4.472-4.471
  C413.654,613.97,415.653,615.97,415.653,618.441z">
      </path>
   </g>
   <path fill="none" id="motionPath" stroke="green" stroke-width="8"
            d="M 0,0 L -250,-470"/>
      <animateMotion xlink:href="#car" dur="5s" begin="click" fill="freeze"
                     rotate="auto-reverse">
         <mpath xlink:href="#motionPath"></mpath>
      </animateMotion>
   </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: thanks a lot , then could you help me again ? why animateMotion attribute rotate="auto" didn't work .

Comment: That is because your car is offset on the page.  So when it gets rotated for the animation, it gets rotated off the page (because it rotates around the (0,0) point.  I've added an update to my answer that shows how to fix that.